# Getting 'File Not Found' on Wordpress Page

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, wordpress

I created a new Wordpress page, I can't access it in the browser and my Apache error log shows:

```
File does not exist: /var/www/website/wordpress/new-page, referer: http://new.comelody.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=315&action=edit
```

Here is Aapche.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName new.comelody.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/website/wordpress

  RewriteEngine On
  <Directory /var/www/website/wordpress>
         AllowOverride all
         Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and this is .htaccess inside the theme:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteBase /test
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
</IfModule>
```

What is the cause of this?

Thank you!

Comment: The cause of this is that the file does not exist. Jokes aside, the first step is to look for the file that doesn't exist according to the error. My bet is that either the file is missing or its name isn't "new-page" but "new-page.php" and you have neither MultiViews or Rewrite active. Providing more info often helps.

Comment: Thank you @Broco, I've added Apache.conf and .htaccess of the theme. adding Options -MultiViews did not help.

Answer (score 1):

Chaning .htaccess inside Wordpress to this solved the problem

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Just as info, in your apache.conf you disabled MultiViews. Also you have to enable it with the "All" switch to enable your desired behavior. That being said, rewrite as you did it is the safer and therefore better option.